# JavaScript longest string in array, with a twist

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I get an array of `int`s, and I'm supposed to find the one with the most digits, however if there are several of the same size (the longest size that is), I'm to return the first one.

I suspect I gotta do something with the index, but I just don't know what

```
function findLongest(array){
  let arr = array.toString().split(',')
  let result =  arr.reduce((acc,cur,index) => acc.length > cur.length ? acc : cur)
  return parseInt(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's take a look at `reduce`:

```
array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)
```

### Option 1:

use `acc.length >= cur.length ? acc : cur`.

1. acc (currently longest length int)
2. cur (currentIndex)

**If** `acc` have bigger or same length then keep the `acc` **else** use `cur`.

```js
var arr = [1, 22, 33, 4444, 5555, 6666, 123, 21];

function findLongest(array){
  let arr = array.toString().split(',');
  let result =  arr.reduce((acc,cur,index) => acc.length >= cur.length ? acc : cur);
  console.log(`first matching longest int: ${result}`);
  return parseInt(result)
}


findLongest(arr);
```

### Option 2:

Since your function use `reduce` it will loop through the array (from left to right) and output the **last one matching**, you can use `reduceRight` to loop through the array from the right (reverse order). You will get the first matching one easily.

(thanks to @marzelin from the comments)

```js
var arr = [1, 22, 33, 4444, 5555, 6666, 123, 21];

function findLongest(array){
  let arr = array.toString().split(',');
  let result =  arr.reduceRight((acc,cur,index) => acc.length > cur.length ? acc : cur);
  console.log(`first matching longest int: ${result}`);
  return parseInt(result)
}


findLongest(arr);
```

Comment: there's also reduceRight() function that starts from the right side of an array

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, to get the max length in the list and then iterate until you find the first occurrence with that length:

```js
x = [56, 783, 231, 2, 5213, 382, 232, 1232, 42, 54]
function findLongest(array){
    let arr = array.toString().split(',');
    let maxLen = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function (el) { return el.length }));
    let result =  arr.reduce((acc,cur,index) => acc.length == maxLen ? acc : cur);
    return parseInt(result);
}


document.write(JSON.stringify(x)+"<br><br>"+findLongest(x))
```